# Create custom array using JavaScript angular reduce function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and trying to solve a solution where I need to parse a filtered array to create a custom array group based on an angle delta > 4, but not to include items in the same group if the distance delta is greater then 120. The distances with delta's > 120 would be put into a separate group even though the angle delta was > than 4. I have a reduce function that groups items correctly with angle delta's > 4, but not sure how to not include items in the same group w/ distance delta's > 120 and push these into a separate array group using a single reduce function. The distances will not always be in order when grouped by angles, so the angle groups would need to be sorted prior to sub-grouping the distances from the angle groups for the delta check to work correctly. Would appreciate any help in solving this.

```
const filteredItems = [
 { id: "1", distance: 220, angle: 60},
 { id: "2", distance: 320, angle: 65},
 { id: "3", distance: 20, angle: 64},
 { id: "4", distance: 25, angle: 63},
 { id: "5", distance: 30, angle: 7},
 { id: "6", distance: 500, angle: 62},
 { id: "7", distance: 145, angle: 20},
 { id: "8", distance: 120, angle: 22},
 { id: "9", distance: 190, angle: -126},
 { id: "10", distance: 90, angle: -122}
]
```

Sort by angles

```
filteredItems.sort(function (a, b) { return a.angle - b.angle; });
```

This works fine to create groups of angles > 4, but not sure how to change the same reduce function to include a secondary check on the same group for distances > 120 and put those items into separate groups using the same reduce function without first sorting on distances.

```
const angleGroupDelta = 4; // separate groups by +/- 4 
let groupedItems = filteredItems.reduce(function (prev, curr, idx, ary) {
if (!idx || Math.abs(ary[idx - 1].angle - curr.angle) > angleGroupDelta) {  
   prev.push([]); 
}
prev[prev.length - 1].push(curr);  
return prev;
}, []);
```

This is the current output by angles differences > 4, but not separating distances > 120 from the same group.

```
   [
        {
          "id": "10",
          "distance": 90,
          "angle": -122
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "distance": 190,
          "angle": -126
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "distance": 30,
          "angle": 7
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "distance": 120,
          "angle": 22
        },
        {
          "id": "7",
          "distance": 145,
          "angle": 20
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "distance": 20,
          "angle": 64
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "distance": 25,
          "angle": 63
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "distance": 220,
          "angle": 60
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "distance": 320,
          "angle": 65
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "distance": 500,
          "angle": 62
        }
      ]
    ]
```

And this is the designed output w/ angles > 4, but with the distances > 120 separated into separate groups which is what's needed.

```
   [
        {
          "id": "10",
          "distance": 90,
          "angle": -122
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "distance": 190,
          "angle": -126
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "distance": 30,
          "angle": 7
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "distance": 120,
          "angle": 22
        },
        {
          "id": "7",
          "distance": 145,
          "angle": 20
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "distance": 20,
          "angle": 64
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "distance": 25,
          "angle": 63
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "distance": 220,
          "angle": 60
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "distance": 320,
          "angle": 65
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "distance": 500,
          "angle": 62
        }
      ]
    ]
```